# What is leafname in authbind port?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server

I wanted to authbind port 992,

while reading documentation it is said that,

> PORTS 512-1023
>
> ```
>    Authorising binding  to  ports  from  512  to  1023  inclusive  is  not
>    recommended.  Some protocols (including some versions of NFS) authorise
>    clients by seeing that they are using a port number in this range.   So
>    by  authorising  a program to be a server for such a port, you are also
>    authorising it to impersonate the whole host for those protocols.
>
>    To make sure that this isn't done  by  accident,  if  the  port  number
>    requested is in the range 512-1023, authbind will expect the permission
>    files to have an additional !  at the start of their leafname.
> ```

Ref: [authbind](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/authbind.1.html)

I could not understand what is **leafname** specified here, so I am unable to authbind port 992, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding **leafname** is the last part of the program name (not including the `/`)

e.g. if you would you like to execute `/usr/local/bin/myproc` the **leafname** is `myproc`.

In order to execute a program in the port reserved area - one should change the leafname to start with `!`

e.g. `/usr/local/bin/myproc` should be renamed to `/usr/local/bin/!myproc`

> Note: If there is no **real** reason for using *ports < 1024* for
>   non-system application, it would be preferred to use *ports > 1024*
>   for such application.

Some pieces of code from the [source code of authbind](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/ucgi/~ian/git?p=authbind.git;a=tree;hb=HEAD)

[helper.c](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/ucgi/~ian/git?p=authbind.git;a=blob;f=helper.c;h=a58e7aae666f30899a9673f2efbaf7b070b8bdd2;hb=HEAD)

```
 117   if (hport >= IPPORT_RESERVED/2) tophalfchar= "!";

 137   snprintf(fnbuf,sizeof(fnbuf)-1,"byport/%s%u",tophalfchar,hport);
 138   if (!access(fnbuf,X_OK)) authorised();

 145   if (af == AF_INET) {
 146     snprintf(fnbuf,sizeof(fnbuf)-1,"byaddr/%s%s:%u",tophalfchar,np,hport);
 147     checkexecflagfile(fnbuf);
 148   }
 149 
 150   snprintf(fnbuf,sizeof(fnbuf)-1,"byaddr/%s%s,%u",tophalfchar,np,hport);
```

tophalfchar is set to be **!** if `hport is >= 1024/2` (1024/2 = 512)

The code is checking for the following type of strings:

- byport/!*hport*
- byaddr/!*np:hport*
- etc

Detailed info about [authbind install/setup/testing](https://www.firebind.com/docs/v1_1x/reflector/authbind.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I also thought of the same meaning and named  /etc/authbind/byport/!992 , which did not work, any guess why it is not working?

Comment: what is the result of  `ls -lsa /etc/authbind/byport/!992`?

Comment: which user / uid is trying to run the program?

Comment: I wanted to add 443 and 992 in authbind, I tried with !443 and !992 , in this case 992 worked but 443 didn't, whenever I try with 443 and !992, only 443 port worked. username is 'proxy'

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ - As I wrote in my answer the *!* should be added when the port is in the range of 512->1023  (1024/2 = 512). so 443 and 992 are in different ranges, and should treated differently. Only 992 which is in the range 512-1023 should have the **!** prefix (!992)

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ - take a look at the link at the end of my answer, it might be useful for configure/test of authbind config

Comment: For `/etc/authbind/byuid/*` to work for both ports 1-511 and 512-1023, you have to use 2 files. For example: `/etc/authbind/byuid/113` with `127.0.0.1/32,21` and `/etc/authbind/byuid/!113` with `127.0.0.1/32,990`.